# Regex efficience/performance comparing these different types of constructions: \btheor(y\b|ies\b) X \btheory\b|\btheories\b

Tags: regex, performance

I am writing an expression in which the building blocks would follow one of these two types (or other ones if you have suggestions):

Expression 1: `\btheor(y\b|ies\b)`

Expression 2: `\btheory\b|\btheories\b` (...all variations of words written)

Since I am newbie, just started in Regex, my point is to know from you overall efficiency, faster output/result of the Regex search considering the real expression will be like this (e.g. expression 1 structure) and running in large database (5.000 PDFs):

`theor(y\b|ies\b).{0,30}\bWORD\b|perspective(s?\b).{0,30}\bWORD\b|approa(ch\b|ches\b).{0,30}\bWORD\b|paradigm(s?\b|as?\b).{0,30}\bWORD\b|method(s?\b).{0,30}\bWORD\b|m.todo(s?\b).{0,30}\bWORD\b|methodolog(y\b|ies\b).{0,30}\bWORD\b`

Comment: Protip #1: Keep it simple.  Protip #2: Test your suspicions: Code up both methods and time them, using whatever facilities your language or system provides. If the more complex option is not *drastically* faster, forget about using it.

Comment: Please tag your question with the programming language you will be using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to drive home @JonathonReinhart's advice, so I will start by copying:

> Protip #1: Keep it simple. Protip #2: Test your suspicions: Code up both methods and time them, using whatever facilities your language or system provides. If the more complex option is not drastically faster, forget about using it.

However, to directly answer your question, expression **one** will be more efficient.  Regular expressions read from left to write and try to eat up (match) as many characters as possible.  So lets say you have the string `theories`.

With `theor(y|ies)`, regex will first successfully match `t`, `h`, `e`, `o`, and `r`.  Then, it will try to match `y` and fail.  Then it will successfully match `i`, `e`, and `s`.

With `(theory)|(theories)`, regex will first successfully match `t`, `h`, `e`, `o`, and `r`.  After failing on `y`, it has to go back and *re-match* `t`, `h`, `e`, `o`, and `r` before matching the final `i`, `e`, and `s`.

Hopefully its easy enough to see that the first one has less possibilities to go through and try to match, making it (ever so slightly) faster.  Also, I think the first expression looks much cleaner..and the fact that it is shorter, will make a big difference in readability if you combine a lot of these together.

If you can't visualize that from my descriptions, check out these debuggers:

- [Expression 1](http://regex101.com/r/mB9fY5/#debugger)
- [Expression 2](http://regex101.com/r/aO8vG0/#debugger)

You can clearly see that as the expression gets closer to succeeding (but still failing), the first expression greatly outperforms because it doesn't have to go back and start over.  Here is some [valuable reading on backtracking](http://www.regular-expressions.info/catastrophic.html) (and how it can drastically cause performance issues).

Comment: Thanks a lot for explaining in depth my expressions! I use Regex in a Citation Manager (Zotero)

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing what programming language you're using to apply this regular expression, nonetheless I believe you could eliminate an awful lot of redundancy like so:

```
(theor(y|ies)|perspectives?|approach(es)?|paradigm(s|as)?|methods?|m.todos?|methodolog(y|ies)?)\b.{0,30}\bWORD\b
```

An expression such as the above will be extremely straightforward and efficient for any modern regular expression engine.  (Probably the redundant version in your original question would end up running efficiently as well, but the simplified version is far easier to read.)

Comment: Many thanks for teaching how to simplify expressions. I am reworking all my expressions just now. I use Regex in a Citation Manager (Zotero)

Comment: Regarding the following expression, do you see any way to simplify that=> concep(t|tualize|tualization|tualizing).?\b Thanks!!!

Comment: `concept(ualiz(e|ation|ing))?` should match concept, conceptualize, conceptualization, and conceptualizing.

Comment: Great, but not matches concepts, conceptualized. Because of end of the wors (s/d) I was keeping the .? at the end of my expression. But when I ad the .? at yours it doesn't work to match concepts, conceptualized... Workarounds? Thanks

Comment: Sorry @user3570966, I missed this. [`concept(s|(ualiz(ed?|ation|ing)))?`](http://regex101.com/r/gK7yO7)